# empty css selector in Outlook email

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-email, outlook-2010, email-templates

I'm updating an email template. Gmail, hotmail and yahoo are working fine with the selector

```
table td:empty{}
```

But Outloook 2010 (mso 14) is not understanding the :empty pseudo-selector ( https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ )

Somebody knows a similar way to get  in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Outlook desktop clients just do not support that pseudo-selector.

Here is a good reference outlining what you can and can't use reliably in each client.
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/